# Generate unique, non-serial order numbers (similar to Amazon)

Tags: sql-server

How do I generate unique, non-serial order numbers (similar to Amazon, flipkart) in Sql Server?

Comment: I want to generate order number like OD102796159039845.

Comment: See the datatype UniqueIdentifier and GUID() / NewID() functions

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Orders
  (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   OrderID AS 'OD' + RIGHT('00000000000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(15)), 15) PERSISTED
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NEWID()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348(v=sql.110).aspx) function:

If you want to pick numbers out of it:( to generate random positive integers )

```
select ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT))
```

Else

```
select NEWID()
```

Comment: Is this "select ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT))" expression will generate everytime unique number?